# after applying the normal map my character looks so weird

Tags: normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

After applying the normal map this is how my character looks pls help. The file is available [here](http://we.tl/t-n2q0p71IQU)

[image]

Comment: please tell a bit more, how does the high poly look like? maybe share your file (high poly + low poly + normal map picture)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: What is the *weird* part of the "thing"? And the color from your normal map is a little bit *strong and wide*. You might want to adjust the **strength** value in the normal map node.

Comment: the weird part is the details does not show up (the texture) and it looks so shainy

Comment: @moonboots i cant upload the blend file or a jpg file i don't know why

Comment: you need to copy paste the url of this page in the field then click on upload

Comment: @moonboots the file is to big i can't upload it

Comment: @moonboots can you give me your email ill send it via https://wetransfer.com/

Comment: you can copy paste the link actually  ;)

Comment: @moonboots copy and paste what link>?

Comment: when you upload in wetransfer, just make yourself the receiver and it will give you a link when the upload is finished

Comment: @moonboots this is the download link https://we.tl/t-n2q0p71IQU

Comment: your character is a bit heavy for my computer and I'm not sure I'm familiar enough with 2.8, but if this is your normal map, why is it not mapped on a low-poly?